# SSSD multiline ad_access_filter

Tags: linux

I'm using SSSD to connect linux machines to an active directory. To restrict access to the linux machines I use the ad_access_filter in sssd.conf. Here an example line:

```
ad_access_filter = (|(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=examplegroup1,OU=Groups,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com)(memberOf:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=examplegroup2,OU=Groups,DC=ad,DC=example,DC=com))
```

For my usecase this filter is very long, as it contains 10+ groups in a more branched OU structure. So I would like to split this line in the configuration file to make it readable more easily. If this is possible, how can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the basic INI file format is simply not guaranteed to support multiline *anything*.  Individual software might implement a smarter parser, but it's not standard, and the one used by SSSD doesn't.

You might consider splitting out the `ad_access_filter` setting to a separate file in `/etc/sssd/conf.d/the_ad_access_filter_goes_here.conf`.  Then put the individual elements of the AD group filter into, for example, `/etc/sssd/conf.d/the_ad_access_filter_inputs.txt` in a more accessible format.  The file extension probably won't be `.txt`, but you get the idea; SSSD itself only looks at `.conf` files.

Then write up a simple script using whatever scripting language you prefer (and know will be available on the Linux system), reading in the input file, joining all the lines together and removing any internal whitespace, and printing the output to `the_ad_access_filter_goes_here.conf` along with a comment like

```
# THIS FILE WAS AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED, EDITS WILL BE LOST
# Generated from "the_ad_access_filter_inputs.txt" on 2023-06-06 14:48:02
# Humans should read that file instead.
ad_access_filter = .....
```

Depending on what scripting language you like to use, you have your choice of how to format the input file.